# Program closes after user input, no reason it should

Tags: c++, input

sorry, I'm very new and have to hurry, so I just wanted to put this up. The code randomly ends after trying the first input (choosing what topic, algebra, basic mathematics, etc.) I've tried other sources, tried reformatting and still don't know what it is. I'm fairly new, so I assume it's just a stupid issue that I overlooked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int calculatorChoice, choiceMath1;
    int addition1, addition2, additionSum;
    int subtraction1, subtraction2, subtractionDifference;
    int multiplication1, multiplication2, multiplicationProduct;
    int division1, division2, divisionQuotient;
    cout << "What would you like to figure out?" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "[1]: Basic Mathematic Equations" << endl;
    cout << "[2]: Figuring out a Grade" << endl;
    cout << "[3]: Algebra" << endl;
    cout << "[4]: Inquiry Sciences" << endl;
    cout << "[5]: Unit Conversion" << endl;
    cin >> calculatorChoice;
    if (calculatorChoice == 1) {
        cout << "What would you like to do?" << endl;
        cout << "" << endl;
        cout << "[1]: Addition" << endl;
        cout << "[2]: Subtraction" << endl;
        cout << "[3]: Multiplication" << endl;
        cout << "[4]: Division" << endl;
        cin >> choiceMath1;
        if (choiceMath1 == 1) {
            cout << "Choose your first number." << endl;
            cin >> addition1;
            cout << "Choose your second number." << endl;
            cin >> addition2;
            additionSum = addition1 + addition2;
            cout << "The sum of " << addition1 << " and " << addition2 << " is " << additionSum << "." << endl;

        }
        else if (choiceMath1 == 2) {
            cout << "Choose the first number." << endl;
            cin >> subtraction1;
            cout << "Choose the second number." << endl;
            cin >> subtraction2;
            subtractionDifference = subtraction1 - subtraction2;
            cout << "The difference of " << subtraction1 << " and " << subtraction2 << " is " << subtractionDifference << "." << endl;
        }
        else if(choiceMath1 == 3) {
            cout << "Choose the first number." << endl;
            cin >> multiplication1;
            cout << "Choose the second number." << endl;
            cin >> multiplication2;
            multiplicationProduct = multiplication1 * multiplication2;
            cout << "The product of " << multiplication1 << " and " << multiplication2 << " is " << multiplicationProduct << "." << endl;
        }
        else if(choiceMath1 == 4) {
            cout << "Choose the first number." << endl;
            cin >> division1;
            cout << "Choose the second number." << endl;
            cin >> division2;
            divisionQuotient = division1 / division2;
            cout << "The quotient of " << division1 << " by " << division2 << " is " << divisionQuotient << "." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "That is not a choice." << endl;
        }
    }
    else {

    }
}
void calculator() {

}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: what input do you provide? If you enter anything else than 1 the programs ends as expected

Comment: What are you expecting this code to do?  I notice there's no loop in it.

Comment: As an aside, you can probably replace all your `addition`, `subtraction`, `multiplication`, and `division` variables with just three variables, `operand1`, `operand2`, and `operationResult`.  I would suggest initialising them with zero.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesnt have any loop, what means, after enter the input , it shows the result and program finishes. If you want to stop your code somewhere (depends on the IDE, this solution is for VS) just type `system("pause")`and you will see what your program shows on console. In case you are not on VS, add `#include <cstdlib>`

If you explain a bit more hat you expect your code to do we can help you  easier.